# How to convert the loop in Tensorflow loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tensorflow

I have written a program and trying to write it with Tensorflow so that I can use the GPU.
Please let me know what I can do to convert it into tensorflow.
**Here is the code for Normal Execution:**

```
def function(array,position,times):
    o = []
    for loop in range(position,30):
        result = 0.0
        for k in range(times):
            result += array[loop-k]
        result /= times
        o.append(result)
    return o
q = [i for i in range(30)]
output = function(q,10,5)
print(output)
```

**Using the Tensorflow I have tried this:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
def function_tf(array,position,times):
    o = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32,(30-position))
    index = tf.Variable(0)
    for loop in range(position,30):
        result = tf.Variable(0.0)
        for k in range(times):
            result.assign_add(array[loop-k].numpy())
            # print(result)
        result = tf.divide(result,times)
        o = o.write(index.numpy(),result.numpy())
        index.assign_add(1)
    return o.stack().numpy()
q = [i for i in range(30)]
q = tf.convert_to_tensor(q)

output = function_tf(q,tf.constant(10),tf.constant(5.0))
print(output)
```

The output is same:

```
[ 8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25.
 26. 27.]
```

But the only fact is the loops in the Tensorflow code still are the Python loop so it will work with CPU and not with GPU. I want everything to happen inside the GPU. Only assignment could be through the CPU.
Please help me convert the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually write that function more simply without loops as the following convolution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def function(array, position, times):
    array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)
    array = array[tf.newaxis, tf.maximum(position - times + 1, 0):, tf.newaxis]
    filter = tf.fill([times, 1, 1], tf.dtypes.cast(1 / times, array.dtype))
    return tf.nn.conv1d(array, filter, stride=1, padding='VALID')[0, :, 0]
print(function(tf.range(30.), 10, 5).numpy())
# [ 8.000001  9.       10.       11.       12.       13.       14.
#  15.       16.       17.       18.       19.       20.       21.
#  21.999998 23.       24.000002 25.       26.       26.999998]
```

---

EDIT: If you want to explicitly recreate the loop in the original code (although it will probably be slower), you can do it with `tf.while_loop` as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def function(array, position, times):
    array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)
    dt = array.dtype
    ta = tf.TensorArray(dt, size=tf.size(array) - position, element_shape=())
    ta, _ = tf.while_loop(
        lambda ta, i: i < tf.size(array),
        lambda ta, i: (ta.write(i - position, tf.reduce_sum(array[i - times + 1:i + 1]) / times), i + 1),
        [ta, position])
    return ta.stack()
print(function(tf.range(30.), 10, 5).numpy())
# [ 8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25.
#  26. 27.]
```

Or, even further, writing both loops instead of using `tf.reduce_sum`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def function(array, position, times):
    array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)
    dt = array.dtype
    ta = tf.TensorArray(dt, size=tf.size(array) - position, element_shape=())
    ta, _ = tf.while_loop(
        lambda ta, i: i < tf.size(array),
        lambda ta, i: (ta.write(i - position, 
                                tf.while_loop(lambda s, j: j < times,
                                              lambda s, j: (s + array[i - j], j + 1),
                                              [tf.zeros((), dt), 0])[0] / times),
                       i + 1),
        [ta, position])
    return ta.stack()
print(function(tf.range(30.), 10, 5).numpy())
# [ 8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25.
#  26. 27.]
```

Since you are using eager execution, you could also directly use Python loops like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def function(array, position, times):
    array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)
    o = []
    for loop in range(position, tf.size(array)):
        result = 0
        for k in range(times):
            result += array[loop-k]
        result /= times
        o.append(result)
    return tf.stack(o)
print(function(tf.range(30.), 10, 5).numpy())
# [ 8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25.
#  26. 27.]
```

Comment: That's a wonderful idea. I will try it. But is h=there a way through which I do not go through the functional understanding and directly have the looping stuff  through Tensorflow? Is there any another way that is equivalent to the way I am using it? Please do share if there is any. I will try this solution too.

Comment: @JafferWilson I have added some alternatives with loops.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will accept your answer. I have a query and I hope you will help me with it. If I use the Python loops and my Tensorflow is GPU based, then will it use the GPU completely or will that use CPU for the Python loops and the rest GPU depending upon my execution statements?

Comment: @JafferWilson Python loops will run in the Python interpreter, but operations themselves may run on GPU. With [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance) you can convert the function into a graph so it will be run entirely by the TensorFlow runtime. I don't know if it's possible to run everything on the GPU (I'm not sure if `tf.while_loop` can even run on GPU), but at least it will not jump back and forth to the Python interpreter. You can read more in [AutoGraph and loops](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#autograph_and_loops).